# Fall as a free action and then use fly skill to end falling as free movement

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, flight, falling

I had a character flying at 100 feet. I knocked an enemy to the ground. Their now farther away than a charge action could get me.

Is it possible to start falling as a free action, and then resume flying under the [fly skill rules of negate fall damage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/fly) as another free action (since no action is listed), and then still have all your actions (except some free actions) left to use?

I assume that if allowed, and you fail the fly check, you fail to fly and thus greet the ground, taking all that fall damage and becoming prone, but still have all your actions.

I'm the summoner archetype that allows me to fuse with the Eidolon, and it's the first flight evolution, so my flight is an Ex. At some point, it might become a  Su.

Comment: Does this character have a fly speed?

Comment: @FrancisJohn Yes, otherwise you wouldnt be able to use the fly skill

Comment: what is the fly speed?

Comment: What is the source of your flight?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Im the summoner archetype that allows me to fuse with the eidolon, and its the first flight evolution, so its Ex. At some point it might be SU.

Comment: @Fering I've incorporated that into your question with an edit (forgot to highlight that).

Answer (score 1):

Flying is the use of lateral movement, straight downward vertical movement is, by definition, falling. As such flight uses a move action. It follows, to me at least, that you can indeed fall for free but to start flying instead of falling you will need to use a move action. This does not preclude catching up to and attacking your newly grounded foe if you have all your actions to call on but does preclude full-round actions when you get to the ground.

Yes if you fail the fly skill check to pull out of the fall you are going to hit with full force and take damage accordingly, unless you have some other contingency in place.

That's only my reading of the rules, a given GM may differ considerably in their interpretation.